# How to calculate $P(XY\leq t)$?

Tags: probability

Thank you for your attention. I have the following problem. $X,Y~Uniform(0,1)$, then what is 
$P(XY\leq t)$?

I know the answer. However, I just struggle on understanding why they solved it that way.

1) For t>=0, the probability is 1. Therefore we need to focus on t<1. 
This means that $X,Y<1$ or if X=1, then Y has to be less than 1.

I am thinking of the problem in two dimensions, x and y, and picking random  t's.

The solution in the textbook is: $ P(XY\leq t)=\int^{t}_0 \int^{1}_0 dx dy  + \int^{1}_t \int^{t/y}_0 dx dy$

After reading the solution I think I need to split the cases while fixing one variable:

1. $X \epsilon (0,1)$ implies Y's maximum value is $t$ because X has to be less than 1.
2. Now, we need to see the values for $Y \epsilon (t,1)$ which implies something else.

I really do not know how to solve these kinds of problems. Please help me, and if you have more suggestions on where I can find more problems to practice I would gladly take them too.

Comment: I hope the textbook specified that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  Otherwise the answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes it says they are independent. Thank you very much. The way I understood it was as follows: since we know that $Y=t/x$ crosses the square of X and Y at points (t,1) and again at (1,t). I just need to integrate over the square X(0,t) Y(0,1), and I will have an irregular form which goes from X(t,1) Y(0,t/x).  I did it that way and finally got the answer.  Hopefully this will help other people too.

Answer (score 1):

> After reading the solution I think I need to split the cases while fixing one variable:

Yes.  The cases are

- When $y\in [0;t]$, then for $xy\leq t$ any $x\in[0;1]$ is viable.
- When $y\in (t;1]$, then we cannot allow $x$ to exceed $t/y$; so $x\in[0;t/y]$

How do we know where to make this split? By examining the domains we're measuring.

By examining the intervals we need: $0\leq y\leq 1, \; 0\leq x\leq 1, \; 0\leq xy\leq t$.

So if we use $\operatorname dy$ as the outer integral, the inner integral must range over $0\leq x\leq \min[1,t/y]$.   That minimum is $1$ when $y\leq t$, and it is $t/y$ when $y\geq t$.

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\min[1, t/y]}\operatorname d x\operatorname d y = \int_0^t\int_0^1\operatorname d x\operatorname d y+\int_t^1\int_0^{t/y}\operatorname d x\operatorname d y$$

---

PS: As Robert Israel commented, this of course assumes that $X$, $Y$ are *independent*, uniform$[0;1]$ distributed random variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, look at the unit square and the graph of $y=\frac{t}{x}$. $P(Y\leq \frac{t}{x})$ is the area under the curve in the unit square.

The solution in the textbook boils down to this:

$$\int^{t}_0 \int^{1}_0 dx dy  + \int^{1}_t \int^{t/y}_0 dx dy=\int^{t}_0  dy  + \int^{1}_t \frac{t}{y} dy$$

If you look at the function in the unit square, you'll see that the function enters the unit square when $x=t$, which is exactly what the last part is expressing.